# Build regular expression

Tags: regular-language, finite-automata

I need to build a regular expression for strings in which the +/- characters cannot stand side by side (must be separated by some other). I got this option: `(a*(+|-)a)*` , where `a` is any character, `*` is the Kleene closure, `()` is for clarity. But this expression does not recognize lines of the form: "+", "-","+ a-" etc. Maybe someone will be able to move me from the dead point. I need regularity to build a finite automaton.

Comment: You can always build a DFA to test your regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That might do:

```
^(\+(?![\+-])|-(?![\+-])|[^\+-])*?$
```

It bounds everything to the single line: `^` to `$`. The lazy quantifier `()*?` ensures that no more then one line is going to be recognized.

The 3 concatenations inside the parentheses are as follows:

- `\+(?![\+-])` if the character **is** `+` the next one must **not** be `+` or `-`
- `-(?![\+-])` if the character **is** `-` the next one must **not** be `+` or `-`
- the previous two have the second character only looked-ahead, and could be combined into one concatenation: `[\+-](?![\+-])`.
- `[^\+-]` any character that is not `+` and `-`

However, you must know that a `regex` is more powerful than a `regular expression`. You need a regular grammar more than a regular expression:

```
S = +T
S = -T
S = @S
S = ε

T = @S
T = ε
```

This grammar is right-regular, and `@` is any character that is not `+` nor `-`. `ε` is epsilon = nothing.

Here is the deterministic finite automaton (where `P=+` `M=-` `@=not + and not -`):

```
  /---- @ ----\
  |           |
  |           v
(S = start/final)--- P,M -->(T = final)---- P,M --->(error)
      ^                          |         
      |                          |         
      \----------- @ ------------/
```